# MUI 6 TextFields with one common label

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to create 6 mui `TextField` for entering 6 numbers seperated with dot, and having only one common label 'Code Number' in one `FormControl`. How can this be done? The problem is the label is inside the first text field only.

```
const codeNumbers = ['code1', 'code2', 'code3', 'code4', 'code5', 'code6'];

<FormControl>
  <InputLabel id="code-label">Code Number</InputLabel>
  <Grid container spacing={2}>
   {codeNumbers.map((codeNumber) => (
    <Grid item xs={4} key={codeNumber}>
      <TextField id={codeNumber} name={codeNumber} label={`Code ${codeNumber.slice(-1)}`} />
    </Grid>
))}
</Grid>
<FormHelperText>Please enter 6 numbers separated by a dot</FormHelperText>
</FormControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

The current behavior is not working because all `<FormControl>, <InputLabel>, and <TextField>` should be inside the `map()`. Code should be modified like to be this

```
<Grid>
  <Grid container spacing={2}>
    {codeNumbers.map((codeNumber, index) => (
      <Grid item xs={4} key={codeNumber}>
        <FormControl>
          <InputLabel id="code-label">Code Number</InputLabel>
          <TextField
            id={codeNumber}
            name={codeNumber}
            label={`Code ${codeNumber.slice(-1)}`}
          />
        </FormControl>
      </Grid>
    ))}
  </Grid>
  <FormHelperText>Please enter 6 numbers separated by a dot</FormHelperText>
</Grid>
```

Have you considered using a placeholder? or the requirement is to use `<InputLabel>`